# combine two of the table Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 mysql table and I want to combine two of the table . my question is how do I make two tables into one query with certain criteria , for more details show images
[Design Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRPoP.png)

Comment: Can you please show us what you have done so far?

Comment: this is my query `SELECT  a.NoTransaksi, a.Kode, a.Nama, a.Satuan, a.Konversi, a.JumlahPesan,b.JumlahTerima from PO_barang_Detail as a, Penerimaan_Barang_Detail as b where a.NoTransaksi=b.NoTransaksi and a.Kode=b.Kode` but result query not same with the image

Comment: You should edit the question when providing codes or more details to the question, instead of adding it in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the below query:

```
select tb.notransaksi, tb.kode, tb.nama, tb.satuan, tb.konversi, tb.jumlahPesan po.jumlahTerima
from terima_barang tb join po_detail po
on rb.notransaksi = po.notrnsaksi
and tb .kode = po.kode
and tb.nama = po.nama
and tb.satuan = po.satuan
and tb.konversi = po.konversi
```

Comment: Thanks very much Darshan Metha, for your solution,

query results as I want

    `select tb.notransaksi, tb.kode, tb.nama, tb.satuan, tb.konversi, tb.jumlahPesan, po.jumlahTerima
    from po_barang_detail tb join penerimaan_barang_detail po
    on tb.notransaksi = po.notransaksi
    and tb .kode = po.kode
    and tb.nama = po.nama
    and tb.satuan = po.satuan
    and tb.konversi = po.konversi `

[Result Query][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7W55o.png